# Convert variadic template ints to switch statement

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I would like to do the following:

```
// function that depends on key to do stuff
template <int key>
void bar()  {...}

template <int ...Keys>
void foo(int key) {
   // WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?
}

std::cin >> key;
foo<1,3,5,7,9>(key);
```

such that it becomes

```
template <int ...Key>
void foo(int key) {
  switch (key) {
      case 1: bar<1>();break;
      case 3: bar<3>();break;
      case 5: bar<5>();break;
      case 7: bar<7>();break;
      case 9: bar<9>();break;
      default: break;
  }
}
```

How can I generate a switch statement that enumerates all variadic template arguments as an efficient switch statement without manually writing the switch statement?

Comment: Do you know what fold expressions are, and how to use them?

Comment: I know fold expressions, but I do not see a simple (non-recursive) solution for the given problem either.

Comment: I do know fold expressions and how to use them, but I don't see a way for fold expression to generate an efficient lookup table such as a switch statement.

Comment: There is no way to generate a `switch` like the OP is asking for. All you can do is either copy the template arguments into a local array and then iterate it, or else call a recursive function, where each iteration/call compares the `key` to a given argument and then calls `bar` if there is a match.

Comment: There is another way by building up a compile time key to function call map. Example :
https://onlinegdb.com/reK71B8aQA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compilers can turn chained-ifs into switch statements in assembly.

A binary fold like this:

```
( [&key]{
    if(key==Keys) {
      bar<Keys>();
      return true;
    }
    return false; 
  }()||... );
```

does what you ask, down to the assembly:

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/5Kd7K9zr6) - change the #if clause between 0 and 1 to swap between hand-crafted and generated switch statements.

Comment: this is amazing! https://quick-bench.com/q/mLfg4peaj7FDHIjpj1kyPxwkSog

Comment: does this also work with MSVC?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a parameter pack expansion with an empty/extra `foo` to close the pack as in the example below.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template <int key>
void bar()  {
    printf( "%d ", key );
}

template < typename = void  >
void foo(int key ) {
}

template <int val, int... Keys  >
void foo(int key ) {
    if ( val == key ) bar<val>();
    else { 
        foo<Keys...>(key);
    }
}

int main() {
    for ( int key = 0; key<10; ++key ) {
        foo<1,3,5,7,9>(key);
    }
}
```

It prints

```bash
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
1 3 5 7 9
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/zE1cE9eob

Comment: This works well.  You can get a better A/B testing if you set `key` equal to `argc` (it removes the extra loop, and prevents optimization of the branches).

Comment: I feel this is much clearer than a binary fold. After 15 years managing remote, low-cost center teams it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Following the example of the Yakk's answer, I propose the following solution that, using ternary and comma operators, avoid the lambda

```
template <int ...Keys>
void foo (int key) {
  (void)((Keys == key ? (void)bar<Keys>(), 0 : 0), ...);
}
```

or, maybe better,

```
template <int ...Keys>
void foo (int key) {
  (void)((Keys == key ? (void)bar<Keys>(), true : false) || ...);
}
```